# MySQL: Query to compare succesive values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
|  Time  |  Cash | Employee |
|----------------|----------|
| 03:30  |  300  | McClane  |
| 03:35  |  400  | Travis   |
| 04:30  |  200  | Travis   |
| 04:53  |  100  | John     |
```

I need to select 2 consecutive values that:

- results in >= 500 (cash)
- both are in less than 1 minute (time) from each other
- are by the same Employee

It should be like this:

```
|  Time  |  Cash | Employee | 
|----------------|----------|
| 03:35  |  400  | Travis   |
| 04:30  |  200  | Travis   |
```

The closest thing I've achieved is something like this:

```
select time, cash, employee from table where (Cash + Cash) >= 500
```

and

```
select time(now() - interval 1 minute)
```

This can give me the - 1 minute but I can't use the "Time" field instead of the "now()" function.

Thanks in advance for any help and sorry for the broken english.

**EDIT.**
A big mistake, it doesn't matter if the the records are not successive, so I can order them by time first.

I need to print the records like this:

```
|  Time  |  Cash | Employee | 
|----------------|----------|
| 03:35  |  400  | Travis   |
| 04:30  |  200  | Travis   |

|  Time  |  Cash | Employee | 
|----------------|----------|
| 05:00  |  300  | John     |
| 05:30  |  300  | John     |

|  Time  |  Cash | Employee | 
|----------------|----------|
| 06:35  |  200  | McClane  |
| 06:37  |  200  | McClane  |
| 06:41  |  200  | McClane  |
```

Thanks to all for replying, I'm trying with your answers.

Comment: What if there are three records within one second all with 200?  Would you want to find these?

Comment: are the records orders in the table? and would it matter if two records of the same employee are within 1 sec but there are other rows in-between?

Comment: I think you need to look at the cross apply option

Comment: Do you have a table definition so we can show a http://sqlfiddle.com/ example?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Yes, 2 or more records.

Comment: @luksch, No, the records are not ordered, but I suppose I could order them by "time".

Comment: I don't understand how the data set relates to the result set. :-(

Comment: you can upvote/select the answer(s) that you like

Answer (score 0):

assuming that `pk` denotes the PK column of your table:

```
    select s1.pk
         , s2.pk
      from (
                select pk
                     , employee
                     , time
                     , @curRank1 := @curRank1 + 1 AS rank
                  from table t1
                     , (SELECT @curRank1 := 2) r1
              order by t1.time desc
           ) s1
inner join (
                select pk
                     , employee
                     , time
                     , @curRank2 := @curRank2 + 1 AS rank
                  from table t2
                     , (SELECT @curRank2 := 1) r2
              order by t2.time desc
           ) s2
        on (     s2.rank        = s1.rank
             and s2.employee    = s1.employee
           )
     where s1.cash + s2.cash >= 500
       and s1.time - s2.time <  interval 1 minute
         ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tc1.ts, tc1.cash, tc1.employee, 
  TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(CONCAT("00:",tc1.ts), CONCAT("00:",tc2.ts))) AS tdiff
FROM time_cash AS tc1 INNER JOIN time_cash tc2 ON tc1.employee = tc2.employee
WHERE tc1.ts <> tc2.ts 
  AND ABS(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(
          CONCAT("00:",tc1.ts), CONCAT("00:",tc2.ts)))) <= 60
  AND tc1.cash+tc2.cash > 500
ORDER BY tc1.ts, tc1.employee;
```

I made a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd60d/2/0) for this.

I am not really sure if this is what you need. I see many possibilities to improve this, but for now you can start playing with it.

***Some issues:***

- this also picks up all pairs of rows with the same employee over 500 that are less than one min apart. This might not be what you want
- I did not assume any order in the table - hence it is difficult to speak of consecutive entries as collapsar asked for.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you want to add up the cash amounts for all events within one minutes after another event.  You can do this using join syntax.  I think a correlated subquery is clearer:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select SUM(cash)
              from t t2
              where t2.employee = t.employee and
                    t2.time >= t.time and
                    t2.time <= t.time + interval 1 minute
             ) as sumcash
      from t
     ) t
where sumcash >= 500
```

Performance on this in MySQL may not be so good.  You can improve performance by having the index `t(employee, time, cash)`.